# send error message from flask API to vue.js frontend if eval function giving error to apply calculation in database table

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, flask-restful

I have JSON file contains mathematical operations to apply it over columns in a database table, I am using the eval function to convert this operation and create a new data frame, sometimes JSON files contains column names not in the database table columns names so that it gives an error in eval function, I want to send message to the user that (your operation can not be done because you enter invalid name = "d/f")

**JSON file looks like:**

{"1": "a/b", "2": "b/c", "3": "c/d","4": "d*f"}

data frame extracted from the database

```
element_df =  pd.read_sql_query("select *from table where id =5",engine)
```

**apply eval function**

```
claculted_df = pd.dataframe()

   for i in calc_list
    try:
     calculated df = elemnt_df.eval(i)
    except pd.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError:
     {"message":"your operation can not be done because you enter invalid name = d*f"}
```

**then create pdf using report lab and finally send it to frontend**

```
class reportAPI(source):

    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('tested', type=inputs.boolean, default=True, required=False)
        # parser.add_argument('key',     type=str, default=None, required=False)
        
        report = ReportResult()
        report, info = report_.create(data, data['tested'])
        get_pdf = report.get_pdf()      
        filename = "output"
        response = make_response(get_pdf)
        return response
#=========================
api.add_resource(reportAPI, '/test')
```

**I want the user to read the window alert with the created error message
here in the test.vue response**

```
this.$axios.post(this.$backendUrl + '/test', jsonData)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.fileData = { data: response.data }
            this.$emit('fileGenerated', this.fileData)
```

the current file:
{"1": "a/b", "2": "b/c", "3": "c/d", "4":" d*f"}

**the error
pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'd*f' is not defined**

the dataframe from oracle

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 10 | 5 | 18 | 2 |
| 15 | 3 | 16 | 4 |
| 20 | 2 | 14 | 6 |
| 25 | 6 | 3 | 8 |

Comment: `{a/b, b/c, c/d, d*f}` is not valid JSON.  It would need to be a list of quotes.  `["a/b", "b/c", "c/d", "d*f"]`.

Comment: Tim Roberts, yes are right, i will update in the question

Comment: OK, then I'm confused.  What is your question?  "d*f" fails because there is no column `f`, just as the error says.

Comment: @TimRoberts , yes this is my question "d*f" fails because there is no column f  and I want send an error message  to the frontend

Comment: Then you need to add a `try` / `except pd.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError:` clause.

Comment: @TimRoberts, Many thanks, now I solve it and I want to send message alert to the user in the frontend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have stated, you can use a `try/except` to catch the error. Then, if the error is caught, you can return an object with the error instead of the data in this case.

It's usually best practice for API calls to return *both* a success/fail boolean and the data itself. So, in this example, you could return the following (represented as JSON)...

On success:

```
{
   success: true,
   data: ...
}
```

When the error is caught:

```
{
   success: false,
   data: "The error message"
}
```

You can use a JavaScript's built in `alert()` function to display an alert, or you can use something like [vue-simple-alert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-simple-alert).